# NASM x64 on macOS using mach_absolute_time - Trouble getting nanoseconds (working code review)

Tags: macos, time, nasm

I am just learning NASM so sorry if I am making some obvious mistake but I cannot understand what I am doing wrong.

Please look into the code below and let me know what is incorrect. It compiles & runs ok, but prints garbage as a result.
I know that the info coming from `mach_absolute_time` is hardware dependent and so it needs to be adjusted with the info from the struct from `mach_timebase_info`.

I created the below test program that artificially takes 1 sec to execute.
It prints the start, end and elapsed absolute mach time info, (that curiously in my machine displays the correct amount of nanoseconds).
But the calculated nanoseconds are garbage - probably related to some error I am making with the math / use of xmm registers and data sizes but for the love of me cannot figure it out.
Thanks for the help!

Example run:
[image]

```
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Testing mach_absolute_time
; nasm -fmacho64 mach.asm && gcc -o mach mach.o
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    global      _main
    extern      _printf
    extern      _mach_absolute_time
    extern      _mach_timebase_info
    extern      _nanosleep
    default     rel

section .text

_main: 
    push        rbx                     ; aligns the stack x C calls

    ; start measurement
    call        _mach_absolute_time     ; get the absolute time hardware dependant
    mov         [start], rax            ; save start in start
    ; print start
    lea         rdi, [time_absolute]
    mov         rsi, rax
    call        _printf

    ; do some time intensive stuff - This simulates 1 sec work
    lea         rdi, [timeval]
    call        _nanosleep

    ; end measurement 
    call        _mach_absolute_time
    mov         [end], rax
    ; print end
    lea         rdi, [time_absolute]
    mov         rsi, rax
    call        _printf

    ; calc elapsed
    mov         r10d, [end]
    mov         r11d, [start]
    sub         r10d, r11d              ; r10d = end - start
    mov         [diff], r10d            ; copy to diff
    mov         rax, [diff]             ; diff to rax to print as int
    cvtsi2ss    xmm2, r10d              ; diff to xmm2 to calc nanoseconds
    ; print elapsed
    lea         rdi, [diff_absolute]
    mov         rsi, rax
    call        _printf

    ; get conversion factor to get nanoseconds and store numerator and denominator
    ; in xmm0 and xmm1
    lea         rdi, [timebase_info]
    call        _mach_timebase_info     ; get conversion factor to nanoseconds
    movss       xmm0, [numer]
    movss       xmm1, [denom]
    ; print numerator & denominator as float to ensure I am getting the info into xmm regs
    lea         rdi, [time_base]
    mov         rax, 2
    call        _printf

    ; calc nanoseconds - xmm0 ends with nanoseconds
    mulss       xmm0, xmm2              ; multiply elapsed * numerator
    divss       xmm0, xmm1              ; divide by the denominator
    ; print nanoseconds as float
    lea         rdi, [nanosecs_calc]
    mov         rax, 1                  ; 1 non-int argument
    call        _printf

    pop         rbx                     ; undoes the stack alignment push
    ret

section .data

; _mach_timebase_info call struct 
timebase_info:
    numer      db 8
    denom      db 8

; lazy way to set up 1 sec wait
timeval:
    tv_sec      dq 1
    tv_usec     dq 0

time_absolute:  db "mach_absoute_time: %ld", 10, 0
diff_absolute:  db "absoute_time diff: %ld", 10, 0
time_base:      db "numerator: %g, denominator: %g", 10, 0
nanosecs_calc:  db "calc nanoseconds:  %ld", 10, 0
; using %g format also prints garbage
; nanosecs_calc:  db "calc nanoseconds:  %g", 10, 0

; should use registers but for clarity
start:          dq 0
end:            dq 0
diff:           dq 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I know what was wrong. xmm reges got cleared after c calls and that is why multiplication and result failed. Anyway the C workaround below to get the timebase ratio works ok, with the full code of the test below.

The workaround is to get the ratio from `mach_timebase_info` from a short C function, and multiply that to the result from `mach_absolute_time` to get nanoseconds.

As suspected in my actual hardware (late 2013 MBP 2.3 i7), `mach_absolute_time` already returns nanoseconds so the factor as printed by C is 1.000. 
(timebase numerator = 1, timabase denominator = 1)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mach/mach_time.h>

double timebase() {
    double  ratio;
    mach_timebase_info_data_t tb;

    mach_timebase_info(&tb);
    ratio = tb.numer / tb.denom;
    printf("num: %u, den: %u\n", tb.numer, tb.denom);
    printf("ratio from C: %.3f\n", ratio);

    return ratio;
}
```

NASM:

```
    global      _main
    extern      _printf
    extern      _mach_absolute_time
    extern      _timebase
    extern      _nanosleep
    default     rel

section .text

_main: 
    push        rbx                     ; aligns the stack x C calls

    ; start measurement
    call        _mach_absolute_time     ; get the absolute time hardware dependant
    mov         [start], rax            ; save start in start
    ; print start
    lea         rdi, [time_absolute]
    mov         rsi, rax
    call        _printf

    ; do some time intensive stuff - This simulates 1 sec work
    lea         rdi, [timeval]
    call        _nanosleep

    ; end measurement 
    call        _mach_absolute_time
    mov         [end], rax
    ; print end
    lea         rdi, [time_absolute]
    mov         rsi, rax
    call        _printf

    ; calc elapsed
    mov         r10d, [end]
    mov         r11d, [start]
    sub         r10d, r11d              ; r10d = end - start
    mov         [diff], r10d            ; copy to diff
    mov         rax, [diff]             ; diff to rax to print as int 

    ; print elapsed
    lea         rdi, [diff_absolute]
    mov         rsi, [diff]
    call        _printf

    ; get conversion ratio from C function
    call        _timebase               ; get conversion ratio to nanoseconds into xmm0    
    cvtsi2sd    xmm1, [diff]            ; load diff from mach_absolute time in [diff]
                                        ; if you do it before register gets cleared
    ; calc nanoseconds - xmm0 ends with nanoseconds
    ; in my hardware ratio is 1.0 so mach_absolute_time = nanoseconds
    mulsd       xmm0, xmm1
    cvtsd2si    rax, xmm0                
    mov         [result], rax           ; save to result

    ; print nanoseconds as int
    lea         rdi, [nanosecs_calc]
    mov         rsi, [result]
    call        _printf

    pop         rbx                     ; undoes the stack alignment push
    ret

section .data

; lazy way to set up 1 sec wait
timeval:
    tv_sec      dq 1
    tv_usec     dq 0

time_absolute:  db "mach_absoute_time: %ld", 10, 0
diff_absolute:  db "absoute_time diff: %ld", 10, 0
nanosecs_calc:  db "nanoseconds:       %ld", 10, 0

; should use registers but for clarity
start:          dq 0
end:            dq 0
diff:           dq 0
result:         dq 0
```